# What is an easy way to remove duplicates from only part of the string in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of strings that goes like this:

```
1;213;164
2;213;164
3;213;164
4;213;164
5;213;164
6;213;164
7;213;164
8;213;164
9;145;112
10;145;112
11;145;112
12;145;112
13;145;112
14;145;112
15;145;112
16;145;112
17;145;112
1001;1;151
1002;2;81
1003;3;171
1004;4;31
```

I would like to remove all duplicates where second 2 numbers are the same. So after running it through program I would get something like this:

```
1;213;164
9;145;112
1001;1;151
1002;2;81
1003;3;171
1004;4;31
```

But something like

```
8;213;164
15;145;112
1001;1;151
1002;2;81
1003;3;171
1004;4;31
```

would also be correct.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nice and fast trick you can use (assuming `l` is your list):

```
list({ s.split(';', 1)[1] : s for s in l }.values())
```

No need to import anything, and fast as can be.

In general you can define:

```
def custom_unique(L, keyfunc):
    return list({ keyfunc(li): li for li in L }.values())
```

Comment: Oh, this solution is nice. If I understand correctly it generates a dictionary with the second 2 numbers as key and whole string as value. so whenever the same 2 numbers appear first one gets overwritten and no duplicates are made.

Comment: @vanjavk yes, that's it

Answer (score 1):

You can group the items by this key and then use the first item in each group (assuming `l` is your list).

```
import itertools
keyfunc = lambda x: x.split(";", 1)[1]
[next(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(l, key=keyfunc), keyfunc)]
```

Comment: Just need to change to: `x.split(";")[1]+";"+x.split(";")[2]`and this solution works!

Comment: I fixed my answer and it is now slightly more efficient than your suggestion.

Comment: @OneLyner, please describe where it  fails, s\he asked for the second 2 numbers to be the same

Comment: @TomRon sorry I misread :) You might be interested in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code on the few first items, just switch my list with yours:

```
x = [
'7;213;164',
'8;213;164',
'9;145;112',
'10;145;112',
'11;145;112',
]
new_list = []
for i in x:
    check = True
    s_part = i[i.find(';'):]
    for j in new_list:
        if s_part in j:
            check = False
    if check == True:
        new_list.append(i)

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['7;213;164', '9;145;112']
```